# tRPC endpoint with a query parameter

Tags: trpc

I am learning tRPC and I wanted to test its endpoint in postman. I have this procedure defined:

```js
worldGreeting: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    return {
        message: "Hello World!",
    }
}),
withName: publicProcedure.input(z.string()).query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
    return {
        message: "Hello, " + input,
    }
}),
```

For the first procedure, I can easily test this in postman by calling the endpoint: `http://localhost:4200/api/trpc/greetings.worldGreeting`. However, I am not sure how to call the endpoint for the procedure `withName`.

I only have this but I am stuck on how to pass the data: `http://localhost:4200/api/trpc/greetings.withName?name=Seven`

I think I am missing the whole point of tRPC or something. How do I pass data in the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, trpc encodes the url.

So, to call its endpoint via postman, you have to use the format: `http://localhost:4200/api/trpc/greetings.withName?batch=1&input={"0":{"json": "Seven"}}`.

It is important to note that if your procedure accepts an input `z.object({id: z.string()})`, then the value of your `json` key in the url should also be `{"id": "..."}` for it to work.